# Creating an mp3 player for GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, mp3

I am creating a web application with GWT that needs to be able to upload and manipulate (play, pause, scroll, etc.) mp3 files from the user's computer. It also has to be able to add time stamps, whose information can later be downloaded. I can't seem to find any simple way to add an mp3 player to my application. Is there some widget pack or something I can download without having to develop it all on my own?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/media/client/package-summary.html ?

The only thing you will be able to do in GWT client side is playing these mp3 files.
Adding timestamps, information you will have to do serverside.